How to create sub-classes that point to the same instance of 1 super class?
In my app, I have a long registration flow with several different screens. I have a RegisterPage that shows a non-scrollable carousel page view with the different registration screens.
Currently, I have a massive RegisterViewModel that does logic and validation for all the screens at once. This is problematic for maintainability reasons, and I would like to split it into several smaller view models.
Each screen, when the user inputs into it, should send data back to the RegisterViewModel's registration data, where it will be stored until the user completes the register flow where it is then sent to the database.
Each screen has different validation logic, but for all the registration screens they share some core functionality.
I wrote this new view model:
class RegistrationViewModel extends BaseViewModel
    with
        RegistrationPageHandling,
        RegistrationDataHandling,
        ContinueActionHandling,
        RegisterActionHandling {
  

  @override
  void nextPage() {
    super.nextPage();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  void previousPage() {
    super.previousPage();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Enables the continue button at the bottom of the current registration page.
  @override
  void enableContinue({bool rebuild = true}) {
    super.enableContinue();
    if (rebuild) notifyListeners();
  }

  /// Disables the continue button at the bottom of the current registration page.
  @override
  void disableContinue({bool rebuild = true}) {
    super.disableContinue();
    if (rebuild) notifyListeners();
  }

  }
}

mixin ContinueActionHandling {
  bool isContinueActionDisabled = true;

  void enableContinue() {
    isContinueActionDisabled = false;
  }

  void disableContinue() {
    isContinueActionDisabled = true;
  }
}

mixin RegistrationDataHandling {


  AccountType? accountType;

  RegistrationData registrationData = RegistrationData.blank() // create default values

  set registrationData(RegistrationData newData) => registrationData = newData;
}

mixin RegistrationPageHandling {
  int pageIndex = 0;
  PageController pageController = PageController();

  void nextPage() {
    pageIndex++;
    pageController.animateToPage(pageIndex,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.easeIn);
  }

  void previousPage() {
    pageIndex--;
    pageController.animateToPage(pageIndex,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.easeIn);
  }
}

mixin RegisterActionHandling {
  Future<void> register() async {} // send registration data to database to register the user
}

This was supposed to be my overarching, "super view model" if you will. Functionality here will be shared across different registration screens.
Option 1:
I tried the following for a registration page where the user sets their account type:
class AccountTypeViewModel extends RegistrationViewModel {
  void setAccountType(AccountType type) {
    accountType = type;
    registrationData.accountType = type;
    enableContinue();
  }
}

Something like this would be ideal due to how easy it is to use, but there's a problem.
As far as I understand, instantiating AccountTypeViewModel will also instantiate a new RegistrationViewModel. For the other registration screens, when I instantiate their respective sub view models, they will also create a new RegistrationViewModel. As a result, registrationData will hold different values for each screen, when it needs to accumulate ALL of the data that has been entered so far.
Option 2:
So I came up with something else to try and fix this problem, and it looks like this:
abstract class SubViewModelRegistration extends BaseViewModel { 
  // no longer extends RegistrationViewModel 
  final RegistrationViewModel parentViewModel;
  // must point to the same instance of parent viewmodel!
  SubViewModelRegistration(this.parentViewModel);
}

class AccountTypeViewModel extends SubViewModelRegistration {
  AccountTypeViewModel(super.parentViewModel);

  void setAccountType(AccountType type) {
    parentViewModel.accountType = type;
    parentViewModel.registrationData.accountType = type;
    parentViewModel.enableContinue();
  }
}

I think this is annoying to use. Typing parentViewModel over and over again is not fun. Especially when this app has about 12 different registration screens. And each of those screens have really complicated validation requirements, where each one has to check and compare data saved in previous registration steps.
I like Option 1 much much better than Option 2. Is there a way to inherit from a specific instance of a super class? That is, all sub viewmodels, when created, all extend from 1 instance of the overarching viewmodel? That would fix the issue of data not being synced across registration screens, and that would also make it so I don't have to manually tap into an instance of parentViewModel.
What's a good course of action here? Is there an Option 3 I haven't thought of?
